# Rigify and automatic weight painting error

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have a model that I am trying to rig using rigify. The bones are placed, the rig generated, but when I try to apply as parent with automatic weights, nothing happens. No weight painting at all (see pictures)

[image]

[image]

If you need the .Blend, I can upload.

Comment: It's better to upload the file

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/odxelpmfzgk99sx/AABohR1f_v3vChj8wlUiYrjya?dl=0

Comment: That is a link to the dropbox folder. The file was too big to upload the normal way.

Answer (score 1):

Clear parent relationship, select the mesh, edit mode, remove doubles 0,001, then parent again.

[image]

Seems to work (i've tried with a brand new rigify generated armature)

Comment: can you be more specific? (0,001)? Also did you place the bones and add or remove any? Did you do anything else to the mesh?

Comment: I tried Appending everything into a new scene and removing doubles. I also have built my own rig just to see if rigfy was the problem, and when I try to add automatic weights it still just creates empty vertex groups. It shows the message "Bone heat weighting failed."

Comment: I also had  the "Bone heat weighting failed" message, until I removed all the doubles on the mesh; try increasing the value of the Remove Doubles Tool: press T on the 3D window and adjust the merge distance.  Here is my rig: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36977. I've removed two fingers on each hand, adjusted the metarig to the mesh, applied the scale (ctrl A).

Comment: [This post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones) provides some more info about the "Bone heat weighting failed" message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the scale of the model. For whatever reason auto weights needed my model to be bigger.I scaled it up then applied it.