# Is it possible to use characters of Manuel Bastioni Lab with the rigify rig?

Tags: armature, rigify, makehuman

I sometimes tried it. I used the existing rig of the character as MetaRig or I deleted it and  created a new on. It was no problem to create the rigify rig an the buttons but it was unpossible to skin this rig. When I tried to make the rigify rig parent of the character with automatic weights, I get the message: "Bone Heat Weighting failed...."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Comment: The ManuelBastioni Models consist of more than one Mesh within an object. In that case, many times the heat map parenting algorithm fails. Separating the body into its own mesh and parenting that should work for you. You need to handle teeth, eyes, etc on your own, but they should be easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is an addon by DanielEngler to do just that.
Link to download:
https://github.com/danielenger/Meta-Rig-for-MLAB
More explanations on BlenderArtist if it's not obvious enough for you (it wasn't for me).