# heat weighting problem

Tags: rigging

I'm new to blender, and I have a problem with rigging. I follow the tutorial to add armatures to the model, but after that, when I press ctrl+p and choose "with automatic weight" it gives me an error says "heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" I tried all the solutions that I found on the internet like remove double, delete or apply all the modifier, delete all the vertex groups, check the transform, rotation and scale(they are all good)
But nothing helps. I don't know if there's any problem with my mesh...
[image][image]
[here is my blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2v7lwsfja45vzek/20180717_k.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I checked that answer before, and tried both of those solutions, but they can't solve my problem

Comment: I have found 3 non manifold vertices, but removing them didn't help. May be automatic weighting isn't design for high vertex counts. I noticed, that if only succeeds even in lower vertex count, when removing intersection faces.