# Blender - Bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I am using Blender 2.78 and as it seems I am facing the most common problem that can be. I am receiving an error: Bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones when i try to Armature Deform: With Automatic Weights.

What I have tried so far without any success:

1. Edit mode on the mesh and Remove Doubles - No effect.
2. Recalculate normals - No effect
3. Intersect (Knife) - No intersections found.

The only thing that helped me was to click `Seperate By Material`. After i have done this my mesh was devided into parts. Like arms, legs, torso, face, etc. All of those when select them and after that try to parent it with `Armature Deform: With Automatic Weights` it was working fine.

However when I've made this to all the parts into which the main mesh was devided i faced another problem which is shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pS6I13QRhG8

Do you have any idea how can I fix the bone heat weighting or how can I fix the problem shown in the video after joining the parts of the main mesh ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Bone%20heat%20weighting

Comment: Although nothing regarding rigging and armatures might have changed from Blender v2.78 to v2.79b but I recommend you using 2.79b :)

Comment: Actually there is. The default rig on 2.79 consists more bones and it's harder to rig. Can you please suggest any step i can take to solve the issue ?