# bone heat weighting failed causes part of mesh to be weighted

Tags: mesh, rigging

[image: Here is a picture of the mesh parented to the rig via automatic weights and after I join it to my other mesh. When I move my rig this happens]

I followed the other solutions to this issue by separating, recalculating normal, checking if there are shape keys then re-joining them after the parent but these don't seem to work.

Any ideas on a solution?

I was thinking I could create a separate bone and try weight painting it manually to it but I am not sure if it will work right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Comment: Apply rotation, location & scale (Ctrl+A) or There might be another bone weighted to the same verts.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I've already tried that solution but has not worked.

Comment: @Toby I've just gone back to try this but it has not worked either. It's the size of a fingernail so could that be a cause?

Comment: Can you upload the file or export and upload that part, so we can have a look, I need to mess around with it to figure it out I think