# MakeHuman Model Rigging - Bone Heat Weighting Failed To Find Solution

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, makehuman

I was trying to apply an ''Armature Deform'' with ''Automatic Envelop Weights'' to my MakeHuman model imported into Blender, but apparently there's a problem somewhere. Here's a screenshot of the model with the metarig visible.

[image]

When the error message popped up for the first time, I divided the rig into different parts (two arms, two legs, the head and the body) before parenting them together, in order to see if there was a part of the armature that was causing the issue. That's a bit of a desperate measure, as I know that if there's a problem it's at the model level.

I tried lots of things, like turning subsurf on before applying the armature deform, removing doubles, etc. Still, the model is supposed to be perfectly symmetrical, and so should be the armature (I rigged it with X-axis mirror turned on).

For once, I thought I'd not get that error with a MakeHuman ''perfect'' model, but yeah, damn it.

Thanks in advance, any advice or help would be quite appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Comment: Well, I had already given a look to this post, the ''Remove Doubles'' tool was one of the first things I tried out. About having ''meshes which intersect'', I don't think it's the case neither - if I'm not mistaken about what that means. Moreover, considering the model was not ''handmade'', it'd be quite strange if it had topology issues (as far as I know MakeHuman is a renowned tool for creating models so...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try scaling up your object and the rig by a fair bit (say 10x) then try again. The algorithm seems to have some sort of hard internal limit for how close vertices can be (or something like that) and thus larger, less dense models seem to consistently work better. After parenting you can scale it back down again.