# How can i animate my object with one bone?

Tags: animation, bones

I`m trying making an animation with an wand to my game, i follow this tutorial from Blender Youtube Channel: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZ3o5tjO51s

I create my wand with 3 separeted meshs and merge with CTRL+j then i create an armature with only one bone and set inside:

Then i selected both armature and wand and click parent with automatic weights.

But when i move the armature in pose mode the wand don't move. Is there a diferent set to make a object move with only one bone

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct procedure in to select in object mode the mesh first, the armature second (with shift select), then press Ctrl P and choose with automatic weights option. In this way moving in pose mode the bone will move the mesh strictly tied. Another (and better) way is to choose the "bone" option, which can be used when the mesh doesn't have to be deformed (in your case, in which you have one bone only, the result is exactly the same).

Answer (score 0):

If you created an armature with a single bone, and after autoweights, your mesh doesn't move with that bone, it's because the autoweights failed.  Blender would provide an error message in this case, but it's easy to miss if you're not looking for it.  You might check out [Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones) if you want more information about how to work around this.

However, here, there are a couple of easy things to do, that are just as easy as autoweights, and better.

1. Manually assign all vertices to that bone.  Enter edit mode on your mesh, select all vertices, and look in properties/object data/vertex groups.  Blender should have created a vertex group with the same name as your bone (maybe, "Bone".)  By default, the "Weight" slider beneath your list of vertex groups is set to 1.0; if not, set it to 1.0.  Then click the Assign button immediately above that slider.  Now, all of your vertices are assigned fully to this vertex group, and if you still have your armature modifier from parenting with automatic weights, you'll find your bone works properly.
2. Alternatively-- not additionally!-- you can bone parent your object to your mesh, rather than armature deforming it.  This is slightly different, but generally preferable for reasons of performance and for cases where object coordinates are used in materials.  In this case, start by deleting the armature modifier that the parent with automatic weights created.  Then enter pose mode on your armature and make sure your bone is selected.  Now, in the 3D viewport, select your mesh object, shift select your armature, and ctrl p -> bone relative.  Now try our your bone, and you'll see that your mesh moves with it just fine.

Comment: To be frank, if the autoweight failed, more often than not it means the mesh is wrong and it should definitely be fixed, especially if it's for a video game asset.