# Rigify bird rig issue?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting, rigify

Sorry if this is a basic question but I'm trying to use the rigify bird rig tool. When I used the auto rig function it didn't bind my mesh at all. Instead it gave me the error *"Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones"*

In searching for a solution, I found this thread:

[heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

and tried removing duplicate vertices (there weren't any) and also tried taking my mesh into C4D (my native software) to refine it and make sure there weren't any intersecting polys.

None of this has worked, so I've come here. If you want me to upload my scene file to google drive, let me know

[image]

Comment: Hello, it would be helpful to [add images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/182088/edit) as well as a [*simplified sample file*](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to better help you.

Comment: thanks! Added in an edit above

Comment: Automatic weight worked well when I doubled the size of the mesh and rig. I don't know why.

Comment: That worked - thank you!