# Mesh wont move with rig

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature

This is my first time trying to rig an avatar, but the end results are that my mesh wont move with my rig like they are still sep. entities even after parenting. I've followed several video tutorials and read many troubleshooting posts, but still can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am pretty new to blender so if anyone would be able to take a look at my file and let me know where the problem lies, that would be amazing and much appreciated! I am trying to create animations for a project that is due Sunday. :/ Wetransfer link below.

https://we.tl/t-ejI4gVXtRJ

Comment: I've not had a chance to look closely at your rig, but for a start you haven't applied the scale to the mesh. It's still showing an error when you try to generate the rig so I suggest you go through this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzJ39ZOhfQ4&list=PLkoR6rvf_v0IJI950MbAv_h7v8MqmcKy8), particularly the part from around 12 minutes onward which shows exactly how to generate the rig and connect it to the mesh.

Comment: Did you select "with automatic weights" during parenting?

Answer (score 1):

You should:

- Remove the 2 *Armature* modifiers from the mesh object
- check and align the bones for the mouth of the metarig
- Scale up a bit the armature (metarig) and object (like x 2)
- Apply their rotation and scale
- Select the object, switch to *Edit* mode, *Merge by Distance* in order to remove all overlapping vertices
- (re)generate the rig from the metarig
- Parent the mesh object to the generated rig *With Automatic Weight*

Comment: Did it work for you this way?

Comment: yes it fixed the problem, didn't it for you?

Comment: Ah ok, it works now - after I made her a titan - 10 meters tall, lol.
The problem is the infamous "[Bone Heat Weighting Failed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598)" error. It's because the duplicated vertices, the intersecting faces of the upper and lower lip, and the mesh of the lacrimal gland and outer side of the eye socket seem to be too dense. I'm surprised that scaling up the model fixed it because the lips are still intersecting.

Comment: yes sometimes it seems like even with a good topology, if it's too dense, you need to scale it up so that it parent correctly, so you need to merge by distance, then scale up until the parentage works