# It won't let me parent the Rig to the Mesh?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, parent, vertex-weights

When I parent the rig to the model it says,"Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" I'm not sure how to fix this?
[image: Bone Heat Weighting]

Comment: Why would you parent the rig to the model? Usually it’s the other way around.

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: have you checked the usual suspects like duplicated verts and mesh intersections? See https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598 for details. And I've just learned that a too dense mesh can cause this error, too. Scaling up the model can help.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to parent the rig to the model, its the other way round. You first have to select the rig you want to parent, and then the mesh you want the rig to be parented to. then `ctrl`+`P` and you should be done.

-Yoshi

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: okay, thanks for pointing out, I hope its clearer now.