# rigify not working on my facial model

Tags: rigging, rigify, rigidbody

followed this tutorial to add facial movements

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiDft_K7D_k&t=536s

followed every step as mentioned
and applied rigging movements
but im not able to move the facial structure

[image]

when i tried to move the lip part the bone is moving rather than the face

not able to understand why is this not working

Comment: Is it only the face that has the problem? If the bones move but not the mesh it could be the weight paint, or the armature modifier, or something else.  You can share your file at https://pasteall.org/blend/ if you want. (after the upload you need to post the URL here, it's the only way to access the file)

Comment: @Blunder i cant paste it as its more than 24mb
any alternatives ???

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bc7vx7svbvywv7/eyes%20faceschnaged.blend?dl=0 
aaded it in dropbox please have a look

Comment: Oh, I missed your answer. It's the infamous "[Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)" error you get here.