# Automatic weights doesn't affect my mesh

Tags: rigging, armature

[image]

Hi, I have an Automatic Weights failure problems, the Armature settings is already on my modifier settings.
i already symmetrize with .L and .R and Did an Automatic weights on my Armature too.

But the mesh doesn't move along with the Armature.

Can anyone help me please??

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Did you "Parented" the mesh with automatic weights? Or perhaps, are the both mesh and armature pivot (origin) points at the same location? Try checking that out!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Im13zdkyhPYz6mV8dTOu0PMOB59AM0H/view?usp=sharing 
here for the files @moonboots . sorry my files is too big to export here  pasteall.org/blend

Answer (score 1):

It's the infamous "[heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)" error. It happens because your mesh has intersecting loose parts (horns, ears, head, body) and some mess in the tail. In Blender 2.8, you will see this warning in the status bar for a moment when you try to parent the mesh to the armature. If you see this it means "didn't work".

Your cow this is easy to fix. Just separate the head's mesh in a separate object. In *Edit* mode, select the head (hover mouse over it, then <kbd>L</kbd>), and press <kbd>P</kbd>. In the screenshot, it's the (*"Badan (head)"*.

[image: fixed cow but missing tail]
<sup>Hey, where's my tuft of tail?!</sup>

The 2nd problem is worse. It's inside the tail. If you peek in the mesh you will see the mess. You can cut off and recreate the bad part. If you don't want to/can't merge the tuft and to the end of the tail, then consider to separate the tuft and join it to the head object.

[image: chaos in the tail]
<sup>There is a little mess inside the tail</sup>

When you have fixed everything just parent *all* meshes to the armature.

Side note: In *Edit* mode, you can get rid of the light blue markers. Select everything, then choose menu entry *Edge > Clear Sharp*.

Comment: alright, thanks a lot for solving my problems. i'm going to try all your step.