# Eyeballs, hair, mouth are moving at different rates from head

Tags: rigging, vertices, weight-painting

I am new to blender and have a problem (seen here: https://youtu.be/i-X78pHNuf4) where the eyes and hair move with the head bone after parenting but at different rates:

[image]

Also I think it was a mistake setting the eyes as one object. I did it initially because I don't need them to move independently. But all in all I've tried redoing the weight painting and re-parenting everything.

EDIT: Here's the file link: https://pasteall.org/blend/f638de78ca124d4da50ef504d21c17d1 and if that doesn't work here's a mirror: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uaVEMdr6QftB3rVTo-TOsQjUxtOXtgv7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you parented the mesh with automatic weights? Separate eye objects are fine. You can parent them to the head and they will move with it. The same applies to a hair cap.

Comment: If you like share a file with (part of) the mesh and the armature. It's hard to tell where is the problem with only the video. https://pasteall.org/blend/ copy the new URL here after the upload. It's the key to the file.

Comment: For the hair I recommend that you parent it to an empty, and then add a rig constraint to the empty, and specify the top bone of the head

Comment: Here's the link: https://pasteall.org/blend/f638de78ca124d4da50ef504d21c17d1 and if that doesn't work here's a mirror: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uaVEMdr6QftB3rVTo-TOsQjUxtOXtgv7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @james what's the advantage/difference of this compared to just parent the hair to the armature?

Comment: @Blunder In the end it's down to personal preference, I just prefer it as it provides more control when tweaking the final position and shape of the hair (from the empty), and I can track the location, and orientation of the hair without it being rendered when I am testing animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you forgot to apply the rotation to the mesh. This causes this weird behavior with the model tilts her head. You have also the *Armature* modifier multiple times added to all objects, especially the body which has it 9 times!

I'm not sure if it's intended that you use the *metarig* as an armature. You can do this for the quick pose but it's very simple and has no controls, IK, or tweaks. The Rigify rig is the generated rig. You need to press the <kbd>Generate Rig</kbd> button to create it.

Steps to fix the model:

- clean up the modifier stack of all mesh objects and remove all *Armature* modifier
- apply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, *All Transformations* to all mesh objects, this includes *Rotation*, *Scale* and *Location*. (The *metarig* needs to have this applied, too. But you have already done this.)
- parent to all mesh objects to the rig with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, *With Automatic Weights*
- use a *Data Transfer* modifier to transfer the vertex groups from the body to the other objects (eyes, hair, tear line, teeth, tongue, etc) if needed. Done this in the example for the eyelashes.
- make sure the *Armature* modifier is on top of the stack but behind the *Mirror* modifier if present. *Subdivision Surface* modifier is last (on bottom).

[image: example]

Hair parented to an Empty which has an *Armature Contraint* (head bone) as suggested by James in the comments and tilt the head a bit more:
[image]

Comment: I'm exporting this straight to ue5 so I just need a functional skeleton but just for clarification where are the armature modifiers located and how do i select all the transformations?

Comment: if you press *Ctrl+A* then a menu pops up. There you can select *All Transformations* which also resets *Scale* to 1, 1, 1. The *Armature Constraint* can be added in the *Object Constraints Properties* tab (on the right side, similar to the *Modifiers* tab)

Comment: Could you walk me through the "use a Data Transfer modifier" step please?

Comment: Sure, Have a look here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/223782/107598 or https://youtu.be/j823wSrHJnA?t=210 The first link lacks a little of an image. Maybe I'll add a few later.