# Rigging wont work

Tags: rigging

I am new to blender and have been trying to rig an octane model but after setting up the rig and parenting with automatic weights the mesh won't move.

[image: octane model]

[image: armature (metarig)]

Here's the google drive link to the .fbx: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zkKDl9vLjv8PFRbryIbRzOad6S7Zlu_F/view?usp=sharing

Any help is appreciated.

upon further inspection the rig is a meta rig from rigify and the 4 bone thumb and the large hip bones were not there on an older save and the fingers were DEFINETLY not that long so there was some kind of issue saving it but i made a new .blend save with these fixed:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tnj1oHTyF03sVtRuKpqu7y9fR2S54FQU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've added screenshots to your question. Can you add more info about the rig?  I wonder if is rig a Rigify *metarig* is. Is it? The selected bone is the *hand.L* bone. Why is there also a complete hand? And why has the thumb 4 bones? Also, why are the hip bones are so large?

Comment: it is a metarig from rigify and these issues seem to be from an issue whilst saving i have a new .blend here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tnj1oHTyF03sVtRuKpqu7y9fR2S54FQU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character model is interesting because it's half man and half machine, a cyborg thing. That is, you have organic and hard-surface parts. For the organic parts *Automatic Weights* can be used, while the hard-surface parts and the gear have to be assigned to single bones else they will deform, stretch and squash.

The following is a brief description of **what you need to do if you want to use Rigify**:

### A. Create The Rigify Rig

- enable the *Rigify* add-on in the *User Preferences*
- add a new Human Meta Rig to the scene, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, *Armature > Human (Meta-Rig)* because we want to have a rig with fingers.
- in *Edit* mode, delete all face bones because we don't need the face rig for this model. Skip this step if you want to keep it. Use <kbd>L</kbd> to select linked bones. **Very important**: There is a bone called *face* that is at the same spot as the head bone *spine.006*. Delete the *face* bone, too! Find it in the outliner if you can't select the bone in the viewport (try a double-click on the head bone).
- scale-down down all bones, move the bones in position so they match the body mesh. Use the *Lasso* or *Box* selection to select the spheres of the bones (head and tail), then move them. Use *Wire* mode for the hands to place the head and tails of bones at the knuckles.
- in *Object* mode, select the *metarig* and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to apply *All Transformations*. Repeat the step for the body mesh (*Octane*).
- you should have now this (*metarig*):
  [image: the meta rig]
- now create the final *rig* with the <kbd>Generate Rig</kbd> button:
  [image: the generated rig]

### B. Weight Paint / Transfering The Weights

If you try to parent the mesh with the *rig* armature you will get the infamous *[Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598)* error. This is because the model is one object but the mesh has a lot of loose parts and they might overlap or intersect a bit. The solution is to create a solid dummy copy as described in the linked question and transfer the weights from the dummy to the original mesh.

In a nutshell:

- duplicate the model mesh (*Octane*)
- save your file because the remesh operation can freeze Blender
- add and apply a *Remesh* modifier with a *Voxel Size* of `0.008 m`. **Warning!** The value depends on the size of the model and a too-small value can freeze Blender (or delete parts of the mesh).
- go to *Edit* mode, to delete the loose parts of the mesh. Select a vert of the body mesh, press <kbd>L</kbd> to select all linked verts, then invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, and delete the unwanted parts with <kbd>X</kbd>, *Vertices*:
  [image: clean up the dummy]
- parent the dummy to the armature with *Automatic Weights*, transfer the weights from the dummy to the original mesh with the *Data Transfer* modifier, and parent the original mesh to the armature *With Empty Groups*:

[image: rigged character]

Almost done...

### C. Fixing The Weights For The Hard-Surface Objects

The *With Automatic Weights* operation assigns several bones to parts of the mesh. This is good for the organic parts but not for the hard-surface parts. You don't want to deform the gear at his belt when the character model sits down.

This can be fixed in *Edit* mode when you [enabled to *Vertex Group Weights* overlay](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/vertex_weights.html).

- select one vert and all linked <kbd>L</kbd>. Make sure you have the vertex active. *Lasso* and *Box* select don't work. If there is no active vert (the white one) then the weights table is not displayed in the N-panel.
- in the <kbd>N</kbd>-panel, give the bone/vertex group to which you want to assign the hard-surface object the value `1.000` and all other groups the value of `0.000`.
- click the *Paste Weights to Selected* button right next to the input box to assign the adjusted weight to all selected verts. Do this for all groups where you changed the value:
  [image: exmple of weight paints]

Here in the example, the round bins on the back were assigned to *DEF-spine* bone (`1,000`), and the weight in all other groups was set to `0,000`. A `0.800` to `0.200` distributed over two bones is also possible, but this leads to size changes when sitting down, for example.

**Examples of the effect:**

Bag assigned 100% to the *thight.L* bone:
[image: bag example 1]

Bag assigned 100% to the *pelvis.L* bone:
[image: bag example 2]

Happy rigging :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can:

Once imported, clear the parentage of the mesh with the *Keep Transformation* option. In *Edit* mode, select all and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals. Scale up both the armature and the object, like 10 times, you'll scale down later and apply the scale. Parent *With Automatic Weight*. Maybe also *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* of the mesh to get rid of artefacts. You'll need to rework a bit the weight in *Weight Paint* mode.