# How do i connect the mesh to the rig?

Tags: mesh, armature

I am trying to make my mesh move with a rig but it doesn't work properly and I am not sure how to fully connect the rig to the model.

I am quite new to Blender

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lmo54lfnu4btp00/AADQHiusut_GLmzyknYhcZnka?dl=0

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: you should provide your blend file so we can check it out. And if possible, use this: https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: Have a look here. It's the same model and Rigify: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/233759/107598