# One more "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" question

Tags: rigging

**(Thanks everybody for the answers! Scaling the character and rig x10 times helped!)**

I've just started learning Blender, currently getting through video lessons and got stuck at rigging. I am sorry, I know this error has been discussed here a lot, I've tried to follow all the advice, but still cannot attach the rig to my mesh.
I will really appreciate any help!

What I've done so far:

1. Merge by distance
2. Symmetrize mesh
3. Recalculate normals
4. Select Non Manifold (here are two eye loops selected, I don't think it's important, especially since it still worked in the video-lesson)
5. Apply modifiers
6. Delete vertex groups
7. Checked scale
   (8) I also tried to figure out which part of the body causes the error by separating vertices/parenting, apparently the problem is somewhere in the face (surprise!)
   [image]

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Check that bone names and positions are symmetrical. IDK why this helps, but it has in the past for me. Got stuck rigging an asymmetrical character once because of that.

Comment: Are you eyes in a separate object, or are they included in the body mesh? Blender doesn't like rigging lose meshes within an object

Comment: Well you forgot to separate the model by loose parts and apply armature one by one

Comment: @moonboots it was attached via google drive. But I've attached it also in a different way. Hope it will be more convenient

Comment: Greetings and welcome to BSE... it's Very tempting to edit title to replace "One more" with "YAF" lol.

Comment: you have 2 different armatures. Also, try to scale up the object + armature, it may help

Comment: @TheLabCat I've checked now, several bones were asymmetrical, I fixed that and also tried to do a new rig, but that didn't help :(

Comment: @James they are a separate object, the teeth as well. The mesh doesn't include any loose parts

Comment: @moonboots could you explain please, what 2nd armature do you mean? There is an armature (metarig) and a generated rig. I didn't parent the rig in the file in case somebody would like to take a look at the error appear.
I also tried to scale them up, it didn't help :(

Comment: Your model is too small.  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones (my answer, number 4.)  Scale the model and armature up ten-fold and it will weight.  After that, you can reduce their size back to your original size if you want.

Comment: @Nathan omg, thank you so much! It helped! First I scaled it just x1.5, it didn't work, but when I did x10 as you wrote in that comment, it worked! Hoooraaaay!