# Why are my automatic weights not working?

Tags: rigging, bones, vertices, vertex-groups

I downloaded this Sonic the Hedgehog model on Sketchfab.com, and I'm trying to rig this model, but I keep getting the same error message.

The error I'm seeing is:

```
Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones
```

I also don't know how to connect his parts so the model can be rigged.

[My blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hpsgjtk1gz4nojo/Sonic_The_Hedgehog.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)   ... Consider searching on [error message](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Bone%20Heat%20Weighting%3a%20Failed%20to%20find%20solution%20for%20one%20or%20more%20bones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of overlapping vertices, in *Edit* mode select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> to *Merge by Distance*