# Model does not move with Rig after enabling "with Automatic Weights"

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender and have a rigged model. I used basic human rig and generated the rig and want to make the model move in Pose mode but after adding Parent >> with automatic weights in object mode and then when I go to Pose mode and try to move the rig, the model does not move. Is there a reason why the model does not move?

Comment: hello, there may be several reasons, maybe share your file so that we can test? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Is there a warning message in the status bar that reads “Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones”? (Related if yes: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Comment: There is no error that shows up.

Comment: @moonboots here is the link to the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xu1HstwBCSoUugO1NMQlhRbXZcbYIwU9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Blunder Thanks for the response but I could not see any warning message

Comment: you have 2 armatures, which is the one you want to parent to, and how are they supposed to work together?

Comment: @moonboots ok that means I need to delete the first armature, but don't know how to do it actually

Comment: I think the 2 armatures are supposed to work together but I don't know how  :/

Comment: @moonboots The first armature has the model in it and I deleted the rig that came with it and created a new rig which is the second armature named metarig.001, but need to figure out how to make both work together

Comment: do you mean the first armature was already separate? I'm not sure to understand this system, I hope someone will help

Comment: @moonboots yes the first armature was separate. Thanks for checking it.

Comment: Did you import the model from MakeHuman?  Whether you did or not, its scale is all messed up, and neither metarig really works with it.

Comment: @MartyFouts Hi, I actually got the model from BlenderMarket

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to merge the rig that came with the model with the Rigify rig? I'm just asking because this makes no sense to merge them. Either use it rig it had or use Rigify (and remove the existing one). It looks like that you deleted several bones, did you? The *Armature* rig only has one hand + forearm and toes everything else is missing. The mesh works with Rigify but you need to clean up the mess first ;-) Rigify has a base rig without fingers and face, and another complete rig. There are a few things to do to get it properly working (especially the eyes and fingers)

Comment: @Blunder yes. I removed the bones from the original armature it came with, but ended up leaving some of them, still learning how to remove the armature properly, I tried to delete the armature but it removes the model when I press Delete on armature, so trying to figure out how to remove all of that and then just work with the new rigify rig.

Comment: Ah ok. You don't need to delete the bones. Just clear the parent (Alt+P) of the mesh. The model does not get removed if you delete the armature or clear the parent. It just reveals the true size of the body mesh, which is 136m! Zoom out a bit or turn the viewport camera and you will see it. To use Rigify you need to scale it down, apply the scale and do a few more things for the fingers & eyes. A face rig is not needed because the model has shape keys for facial expressions. But the shader is not ideal and needs some tweaks, too.

Comment: @Blunder ok thanks for the tip. I will work on it and see what I get

Comment: I was going to post an answer but it's hard to keep it short. I try to finish it later. All in all the model works with Rigify. You can use the full human meta rig so you can use the jaw controller to open her mouth. https://imgur.com/a/JM0KlR0 I can upload the file if you need it for reference.

Comment: @Blunder yes, sure that will be great if you could upload the file. Thanks