# character rig left arm wouldn't stick to the body and the legs do not move

Tags: modeling, materials, rigging, rigid-body-simulation, rigify

This is my character model[image]

And the right arms do stick to the body but not the left arm. Can anyone help with this?
[image]

Also the legs except for the shoe do not seem to move. I really wanted to know how to make them move properly.
[image]

Are there stuff I can do to fix this?
Rig Link: https://www.mediafire.com/file/1n2xnoc9ifkocx8/jujurighelp.blend/file

Answer (score 2):

There a few things you need to fix:

**1)** To have the arms and legs bend in the right direction you need to adjust the *metarig* and make the elbows bend a tiny bit backward and the knee forward:
[image: elbow fix]<sup>Top view on the metarig to fix the elbows</sup>

Then update the rig with <kbd>Generate Rig</kbd>. Make sure the *rig* armature is visible when you press the button.

**2)** The arm doesn't move because you probably got the [Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones). This is because the arm (named *Hand*) has loose vertices. Remove them and the *With Automatic Weights* operation will work.

- the parts are tiny. But with <kbd>L</kbd> you can select the loose mesh parts. Delete the hidden, broken sphere. Select all parts and hide them <kbd>H</kbd>. Then invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and you have the bad parts selected: 
  [image: arm mesh]<sup>Arm with loose mesh snippets</sup>

**3)** The arms and legs need more edge loops else they cannot bend properly. Add some loops and parent the mesh to the rig again *With Automatic Weights*:

[image: more loops]

Before (only 1 loop):
[image: leg bad]

After (more loops):
[image: leg good]

**4)** The weights of the hair and eyes need to be fixed after *Automatic Weights* (it's not perfect) because the hair will move with the hands and the eyes stick into the head. A quick way to do this is to assign them only to the head bone which it *DEF-spine.006*

- select the *Hair*, look for the vertex group *DEF-spine.006* which gives the bone influence to the mesh. We keep only this group and delete all other groups.
- lock this group with the "lock icon", then select *Delete All Unlocked Groups* from the menu to get rid of all unwanted bone influences.
- unlock the group again
- just to be sure the bone has full weight to all vertices of the mesh switch to *Edit* mode, select everything <kbd>A</kbd>, and press the <kbd>Assign</kbd> button in the *Vertex Groups* section to assign the hair mesh to the *DEF-spine.006* group.

Repeat the steps for the eyes!

[image: vertex groups]

**5)** Lower the levels of the *Subdivision Surface* modifier to 1 & 2 or 2 & 2. Right now, it's 4 for the viewport and only 2 for the render. Better go with a low value and enable the [Shade Shooth](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/shading.html) option.