# Humanoid Mesh not attaching to Rigify/Armature (Tried other similar posts on here already)

Tags: rigify

I'm trying to use Rigify to make a humanoid character easily animate-able. I've tried YouTube and Google searches (including other posts on here) and it seems like the most common thing is not parenting correctly.  I am selecting the mesh, then the rig (so it is yellow and the mesh is orange), hitting CTRL+P and parenting with automatic weights. I've also tried a few things just to see what happens, like parenting to the armature as well as the rig, parenting to one or the other, etc.  I just can't seem to get it to work!

I think I'm safe in saying I am parenting correctly, so it must be some other setting or issue, perhaps with the mesh itself?  I joined the mesh together with the exception of some items which are in their own collections.  After parenting with automatic weights I used CTRL+TAB to check out Pose Mode, but the rig doesn't move the mesh.

I used the metarig for humanoid characters and removed the face bones (including the one hidden in the head bone) and three of the finger bone chains because they're not needed as far as I know for a more "mitten-like" hand.

I noticed an error in the console and I'm hoping that this vague error might have some simple solution behind it that I just do not know about.  I'll be adding in images below so you can see some of the setup/settings as well as the error.

If you'd like the .blend file to take a look (whoever is kind enough to attempt to help) I've stashed it in DropBox and you should be able to access it here: [LowPoly_Hero_001.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzx6thnn6e4gtac/LowPoly_Hero_001.blend?dl=0)

[image: Generate Rig]

[image: Rig Generates Quickly and without Issues]

[image: Parenting with Automatic Weights]

[image: Pose Mode Failure]

[image: Error Code from when Parenting]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)   https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=bone+heat+weighting+failed+to+find+solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the warning is that you have a non-manifold mesh.

The solution that will get you past the error:

- select your character.
- In edit mode *merge by distance* (shortcut <kbd>M</kbd> and select *By Distance* from the popup menu
- parenting will now work.

This seems to leave you with a pretty good weight painting.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I could have spent many more hours cursing at my computer screen trying to find the solution to the wrong problem!  Marked as solved.  Thanks again, and if you have the time please let me know how you discovered this (so I can learn from my mistakes).

Comment: When I was first learning rigging, I ran across the problem, so I searched the internet for the error message.  This turned up a lot of discussions about what can go wrong to cause automatic weight painting to fail.  Since you had a low poly rig, I simply tried the first possible cause and it turned out to be your problem.  Auto weight will fail if there are duplicate vertices, your case; or it will fail if there is overlapping (non-manifold) geometry.  If it hadn't been vertices I would have looked for overlapping next.

Comment: Excellent, thank so much!