# Rigging my model doesn't work

Tags: rigging

My model isn't responding at all when I parent it to the armature I have set up for it. It is clearly parented because it can move around but it does not move with the bones of the rig when I go into pose mode. Example gif below. Please help I'm so tired.

[image: Parenting with Automatic Weights]

Comment: Please share your blend file. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Look at the status bar. See the yellow warning for a few seconds? It's the infamous [Heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598)