# heat weighting issue

Tags: modeling, bones

Here is my blend file: https://ufile.io/ufbk6otu
It's too big for the usual blend file upload sites

And before you send me here [heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones) I have tried this as much as I can understand from it.

When I parent the bones and mesh, I get the error: "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones"

Anytime I have ever dealt with bones and mesh, I always get this error and I can never figure it out. Can you check my file out and explain what is the issue, pls?

Comment: I know this is old, I'm just doing what I can to get all of these same questions linked back to a single, canonical version of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first *Merge by Distance*, it looks like you have overlapping vertices. Then scale up a lot both the object and the armature (like 5 times), apply the scale, parent the object to the armature, it should work. Scale down if needed. It looks like when the topology is too dense it won't work so sometimes you need to scale up. As a side note, do you need so many faces?

Comment: Thank you the trick was the scaling. I didn't think that a small scale would affect the parenting. Thank you. And probably don't need that many faces. I think I can reduce that with the decimate, right? How would you fix that

Comment: you could try Ctrl E > Unsubdivide. If it doesn't work well you can select edge rings, Select > Checker Deselect, Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops, X to dissolve edges

Comment: I didn't know you could unsubdivide something. I wish I knew that months ago when you were helping me with my cube honeycomb issue. I avoided the subdivide modifier because I was afraid of it. :P

Comment: I don't remember the honeycomb, but be careful because it doesn't always work well so you can't always count on unsubdivide, always keep a version of your object with the Subdivision Surface unapplied. Also sometimes if you can, don't apply the Subdivision Surface. Typically for a character that is supposed to be animated in Blender, you don't need to apply the Subsurf modifier

Comment: Maybe you weren't there for that one, you have helped me so much that I assumed you were there for that one too :) 

Sadly, I didn't mean to apply the modifier to the duck. I used the bool tool and united many of the parts, and in doing so it automatically applied the modifier. When using the unsubdivide can you change the level like you can when changing the regular subdivide from the default 1 to a 2 or higher?

Comment: yes, when you unsubdivide, check the Operator box (last operation box which is on the bottom left of your 3D view), play with the factor