# Parenting armature to mesh results in unexpected behaviour

Tags: armature, parent

everybody. I have spent almost 6 hours trying to fix this. I am probably missing something really stupid here.

I have a simple Spine -> Neck type armature. I am parenting the Armature to the Mesh with automatic weights. When I switch to pose mode, and try to move the armature nothing moves. I am attaching the screenshots

[image: Outliner showing parenting]

This is my project structure.

[image: more outliner screenshooting]

I have obj and fbx versions of the model and I tried it with both

[image: screenshot showing 3d workspace]

The model was sent to me by the 3D Artists that the company out sources to.

I am tired of talking to them to fix the problem. Maybe somebody here can help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to parent the mesh to the armature again and check the status bar if you see the infamous "[Bone Heat Weighting Failed to Find Solution for One or More Bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)" error. Watch closely because the message is visible only a few seconds and then disapears.

Comment: An alternative way to check is to switch the viewport to the _Info_ window and scroll back through the window looking at messages.