# Problem with rigging once meshes are joined

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging

Hi I’m new to blender and just learning how to rig a character model.

My problem is my character model is made up of multiple meshes I’ve joined via Ctrl J. Once I apply any kind of a rig with automated weights some of the meshes that have appeared to have joined, do not follow the armature like the other objects do.

I can’t find any abnormalities with the objects not moving with the armature.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: providing your blend file would help to figure it out...

Comment: Parent the mesh to the armature again with automatic weights and check the status bar if you see the "[Bone Heat Weighting Failed to Find Solution for One or More Bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)" error. Watch closely because the message is visible for only a few seconds and then disappears.