# Armature Deform Not Working Cased by Mesh Size [Solved]

Tags: armature, bones

Solution: Objects were too small. After scaling them up 4 times and re-parenting, bones are working. Discovered the answer from one of the comments in this [**post**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones).

There is the problem:

1. The objects are parented to Armature Deform->Automatic Weight.
2. After parenting, objects move along with bones. However, when bones are rotated in the Pose mode, the **top 9 pieces** are not rotating.
3. The error message from Blender is: [image]

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: There are dozens of questions here that address this.  Basically, your mesh has a problem, probably that it is non-uniform.  See [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/42221) for a discussion of the problem and the answer.  Edit your mesh and merge by distance to remove dups as a start towards fixing the problem. Automatic weights will continue to fail until you fix the non-manifold issue.

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thanks, everyone! The problem is the scale. My mesh was too small. After I scaled it up 4 times, bone works.