# Unable to pose model rigged with automatic weights

Tags: rigging, bones, pose-mode

I've created an armature, parented the model with automatic weights to it, everything seems fine in processing, but when I try to pose individual bones in pose mode, the model is static.

I've uploaded a video of the issue here:
https://youtu.be/vkBK3ZknerM

All vertex groups seem unassigned in weight paint mode.
Blender version is 3.1

I've done this type of rig successfully dozens of times, any idea what I'm missing now?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You omitted fact that Blender freezes when you parent, and that it ends up with the error "bone heat wreighting failed".  Does this answer your question? [Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Comment: thank you, seems like the model has multiple intersecting objects and I hadn't realized