# how to fix the error : Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones?

Tags: rigging, bones

I have been getting the error (Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones
) when trying to parent with automatic weight. I have looked through my model to check if there are any disconnects and I couldn't find any. I have also used the cleanup tool to get rid of any duplicate vertices. I assume I have missed something, Could anyone help find where I went wrong?

[image: screenshot]

File ------> [image]

Comment: Try key 'M' > Merge By Distance. It removes 6 duplicated vertices with the default distance. After you got rid of them the operation 'parent with automatic weights' works.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones?rq=1 has a variety of potential causes for this; I know of no cause that isn't listed in an answer on that page.  I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of that question (there are about a bazillion questions regarding this, and we try to keep it organized...)  That message above is BSE pretending it's me, I don't like it when it does that.