# New user, rig will not attach to mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, armature

New user here, here is what I know:
Once a mesh is done and a rig is created, use CTRL + P and select the armature LAST, choose automatic weights, and the mesh SHOULD move and deform with the rig.

I have achieved this using a simple cube with only 2 bones, and previously achieved it on a more complex rig and mesh with 12 bones.

However, I have tried 3 different meshes and rigs tonight, all with less than 15 bones total, and the darn mesh WILL NOT ATTACH to the rig! I pose the rig, and my model just stands there.

Ive been doing the correct thing, based on all my research, and it succeeded before, so why not anymore? It really is a very simple rig and I can't get it to attach at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please share your file so that we can try: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Check this solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones

Answer (score 0):

Is the mesh your trying to use Automatic Weights is made of triangles or quads?

Usually, when trying to use automatic weights on a triangle mesh doesn't work.

You will have to manually do paint weights for it to work.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help! My mesh is made from quads. I will try another few possible fixes tonight, and if nothing works, I will give you all one of my failed files to see what's up. :)

Comment: I've been trying to pop my file on here, but it does not seem to be able to be uploaded to this site?

Comment: @user150275 try using https://blend-exchange.com/ for uploading file and share the link here.