# Any faster way to get more accurate automatic weights when applying the rig to the mesh?

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image]

I'm new to Blender and I have been looking into tutorials on character modeling.

I want to at least use rigify correctly to get the best experience and the proper way of weight painting, However, whenever I watch videos of using the rigify addon they don't seem to have major problems like weight painted to various parts of the mesh.

Manually weight painting seems a bit confusing because I'm not sure if I'm applying weight paint to the correct components of the rig. Has anyone had this error before?

Face orientation of the model:

[image: face orientation]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yKlieWkdOMY-KrH0FMLHYHJ12aSv5hIu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you checked the [face orientation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/145751/107598)? Can you share the file?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yKlieWkdOMY-KrH0FMLHYHJ12aSv5hIu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You haven't checked the face orientation, have you? The mesh is inside-out. And you should move the metarig and model up. Have a look here https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/273304/107598 (points 1+2). Furthermore, your mesh looks great with the exception of a few ngons at the back of the shoulder. I would try and make them quads. Also, the knee patches are at the back of the knees. But they should be at the front where the mesh needs to be stretched. Have a look at the elbows. There it is correct. Finally, you need to parent the eyes to their bones & the hair to the head bone (spline.006)

Comment: Thank you so much! You solved one of my biggest issues with rigging