# After Rigging weird model deformation

Tags: mesh, weight-painting, rigify, pose-mode

This is my first time making a model so I probably made a ton of mistakes while building it but I've moved on to try to pose it for my class. At this point I've applied all modifiers and joined everything but the eyes, mouth, and, eye lattices together. I am still working on weight painting so that could be a problem. When I move the rig though those pieces that are stationary don't move at all. Before I joined everything there were a lot of pieces to the model itself. I used rigify.
I can post more screenshots later to clarify things too.
Thank you!

[image: The weird deformation I was talking about]

Comment: The problem is most likely the weights. Have you weight painted it manually or did you use automatic weights? For the latter check the normals of your mesh. If they are flipped the calculation of the weights does not work properly.

Comment: @Blunder Thank you! I've been weight painting and you're right it does seem to be the problem! I used auto weights so I'll have to comb through to check my normals. Also while painting, my Vertex Groups seem to have a few copies like I have "DEF-upper_arm.R" and "DEF-upper_arm.R.001"... should I delete those copies or leave them?

Comment: You can check the normals with the *Face Orientation* overlay: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273345/107598. The red color means the normals are wrong. -- No, don't delete these vertex groups. They are needed. The generated rig has 2 bones for each limb. They are so-called "twist bones" and are needed to rotate the hands and the thighs mainly. Because of this, there are these "copies" of the vertex group. But it's not a copy. Have a look at bone layer 30 (the 3rd layer from the right in the 2nd row). All deformation bones have the *DEF-* prefix and only these bones move the mesh.

Comment: The bone layers are in the *Object Data Properties* panel ("green running man" icon) of the armature (*rig*), in case you don't know.

Comment: Try parenting with Envelope Weights if you used Automatic Weights;  I solved a similar problem recently with that.  First be sure to unparent, and delete all Vertex Groups, before re-parenting.  Also be sure that any pole or IK bones have *Deform" unchecked (disabled).

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll be trying out your suggestions!