Cloth keeps sliding off of rigged character
Honestly I dont know what to do now, am trying to make clothing for my rigged character but for some reason the cloth keeps sliding to the X axis for no reason, now at first I just thought its a left over effect from all the tomfoolery I did, but when I opened a new file it happened again, but instead of sliding off it just clumps together while also getting pushed to the X axis.


It's the same problem as here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/273304/107598 (point 2). The normals on the right side of the model are flipped. If you turn on the Face Orientation overlay you see that one side is red. It's inside out. So the cloth is sucked into it because it wants to get "out". This causes crumbling and wandering. I recommend applying the Scale to the cloth and the model (Ctrl+A in Object mode). Also, make the lower arm and hand a part of the body. If they are separated they need their own Collision modifier and the elbow will deform badly.

Have a look here if you don't know the Face Orientation overlay: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216140/107598

Oh well thank you for the simple fix!
