# Set parent to automatic weights leading to mesh not following armature

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm trying to build a rig for a Cthulu picture frame.

I am following this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jw30S-Oepyo

I get to the part where they set automatic weights, but when I try to move it, only the armature moves, not the model.

What should I do? First time really using Blender so I have no clue what I am doing.

Here's the link to the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eQdiXbrcJ_kGXUZnrwK_x_ijfA2PdbTe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: parenting With Automatic Weights works fine for me, when you do it, do you at least see the "Set Parent to" pop-up menu?

Comment: It matters which object you select first. Do you know this?

Comment: I select the mesh then the armature. Then I see the set parent pop up menu. I click it go into pose mode and try to move things around but the mesh doesn't move along with it.

Comment: For me, it doesn't work. There is the infamous [Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598) error. It works if I apply the *Remesh* modifier first. Also, apply the *Scale* to the armature object (Ctrl+A > *Scale* in *Object* mode). Then the rig works fine with automatic weights.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the mesh(model), go to edit mode ,hit P, then select separate by loose parts.
Back to object mode,select all the mesh to be rigged. Parent it to the armature with automatic weights as before and then see if it moves.
Worked for me.
You can then join the mesh after.

[source]
https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/xtceth/comment/iqqzo7b/