# I am very new to the rigify add-on on blender and have been having problems with rigging

Tags: rigging, rigify

So I just started to come back to blender just to relearn it, one of my major issues with it was rigging. I just heard about the *rigify* addon recently and decided to try it out. I finished doing my weight painting on the mesh and now I am confused about how to align it with the mesh and armature. Is there anyone familiar with the rigify addon that can help me?[image]

Comment: You should move the mesh and the armature to the world origin and then apply the *Location* to them (Ctrl+A in *Object* mode). This way the root control (the big circle with the arrows) is on the ground and your character, too. Otherwise, she will be sunken into the ground when you animate her.-- Have you used *Automatic Weights*? Have you seen the warning [Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598) in the status bar? (it disappears after a few seconds)

Answer (score 0):

I've used it a bit and I think it's much easier to parent with automatic weights and then adjust the weight painting from there as needed. If you line up the bones properly before parenting it is normally pretty spot on, just needs minor adjustments.