# model and skeleton not moving together

Tags: animation

I am making a bird animation, but the model is not moving together with skeleton.
I am a beginner, so I tried the tutorial from beginning but nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: could you please share tutorial link?

Comment: @Muzammil it was this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcuxN7cqwPo&ab_channel=Dwight but just went through this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmiZ6VkSJBE&ab_channel=ChipperVideos

It seems like the parenting option is not working

Comment: ok, found a Youtube tutorial that helped Just had to merge vertices  there was too much stuff going on in the model

Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones

his is the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VLqDctzvAk&ab_channel=DeepakGraphics

thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)