# Bones not attaching to mesh

Tags: armature, bones

So i made the armature and parented the bones to the mesh (i made certain the mesh was selected first and that *scale is applied*) and parented with automatic weights, but the mesh still doesn't move. I have looked into other people with the same problem but their solutions didn't work for me. I would appreciate some help, thanks!
Here is the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pC2k3mtHmufpP9AuG-CDxVUgbVE1JBcb/view?usp=sharing

[image: Bone is sticking out of the arm]

Comment: First apply the scale of the skeleton (in Object mode select it and hit CTRL+A, choose Scale). Also remove the doubles of your mesh (select the mesh object, go to Edit mode, select everything and hit ALT+M, choose Merge By Distance). Then try again the parenting.

Comment: As mentioned by FFeller, the mesh has duplicated vertices. They cause the infamous [Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598) error. You see the message for a short time in the status bar after the *Parent To > With Automatic Weights* operation. It means, that the operation has failed and the rig won't work properly.

Comment: FFeller's comment solved my problem but i appreciate the extra info, Blunder. My mesh was indeed made my combining like 4 different meshes. It looked fine so i thought it was ok, but next time i'll make sure there are no duplicates, thanks a lot for the help guys!