# Rigify not parenting rig to mesh. No deformation happening

Tags: animation, bones, rigify

Trying to rig this polycam elf in the shelf that I cleaned up. Managed to get bones in place and the rig actually looks appropriate.

Everytime I parent, the mesh does not move with the rig in pose mode.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tKDXnMBTjMmUGin9WXFiOprXf55OOGH_/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones). It's point 2 of the accepted answer. You might have cleaned up the mesh, but it's still a mess. When I try to parent it, Blender shows this "heat weighting" error. Merging vertices by distance with the default 0.0001 already deleted 3 vertices, going to 0.001 removed 24605(!) and it's still a complex mesh. After doing that, parenting worked without error (but still not perfect).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the bad topology of your model. After I applied a decimate modifier to make the topo less dense, it worked fine.
I'd strongly advise to make it cleaner than this though

[image]

Comment: ...yeah, that's why I marked it as duplicate question and linked to an answer.