# Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones - Already Tried Merging

Tags: rigging

Already tried Merge by Distance and it didn't work. I had it working at some point but deleted armature and restarted due to some errors. Can someone help me find my issue, I don't want to recreate the mesh. I'd prefer to use the mesh I have now. Thanks!

[Project File](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-tsSdBBuEuFAJftwxknAiteKhwGcPrOH?usp=share_link)

Comment: For me, this has typically been because the mesh has disconnected pieces. Consider making them separate objects.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the scale of the armature and object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. Unparent the object with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. In *Edit* mode recalculate the normals of your object as they are flipped with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. *Merge by Distance* to remove the overlapping vertices with <kbd>M</kbd>. It still doesn't work because the mesh is a bit too dense, so increase the scale of both the armature and object (like x 5), parent With *Automatic Weight*, then bring them back to 1:1:1.

Comment: This worked thank you very much moonboots you are a legend