# Rigging a model from Kaedim/Midjourney

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, topology

I am new to Blender and used Kaedim/Midjourney to create a 3D model from pictures. I have a puppet that I want to turn into a rigged 3D model to create poses and animations. I give the meshes a color, create a bone structure, select all meshes, select the armature, and hit `Ctl-P`, then `With automatic weights`. I get the error `Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones`.

I found [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones) that suggests joining all meshes and removing duplicate vertices. I join all meshes and the process fails. I select only the central mesh, and the process also fails. I select an object and merge vertices by distance, but above 0.002m I delete some faces, and below it I remove no vertices.

You can check the [.obj model from Kaedim](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pha612b0sqy9wi4/Ginja.obj?dl=0) and the [.blend model colored and with bones](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aeuc1el14w80oum/puppet.blend?dl=0). (Note: the puppet is proprietary and I have a license for its use.)

How else can I fix the topology and rig this puppet? If that's impossible, what makes models from Kaedim impossible to rig?

Comment: Hello, you have overlapping vertices, select all in Edit mode and press M > Merge by Distance and parent again

Comment: Thank you moonboots. I just tried again, and now it worked. I don't understand what I did wrong the first time, but you saved me a lot of work. Can you please write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I could rig your model with automatic weights:

Starting from your file, select the body, go to edit mode, select all, press Ctrl E > Clear Sharp.

Then press M (merge by distance 0.0001)

Then press Aly J (Tris to Quads).

Now in object mode you can parent the body to the armature with Ctrl P > Automatic weights.

For the others spare parts you can simply select one of them, shift select the armature, go to pose mode, select the relevant bone and press Ctrl P > Bone. Repeat for all.

You will need some manual weight paint tweaks, anyway.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution. I tried the comment from moonbots and that did it. I don't understand why it didn't work the first time; probably because I'm new to Blender.

Comment: I edited the meshes to remove some kinks (Biset tool + fill), removing vertices by distance, and the rigging failed with the same message. I then tried your method and it worked, so I'm accepting it.

Comment: Can you explain the advantage of triangles to quads for rigging?