# How to Create a Model That Collides with Itself

Tags: modeling, rigging, collision

I have recently started learning Blender and have stumbled upon a dilemma in the model I am working on. The upper portion of the thighs on my model are meant to collide slightly before they connect to the body but also retain their shape when the legs aren't together. In other words, I don't want the inner face of the thighs to appear flat when the thighs aren't touching and do want them to appear flat when they are touching. Basically, I want the model to collide with itself and deform the inner thigh much like what would happen in real life.

The difficulty I'm encountering is how to model my character to acheive this. At first, I tried allowing the faces of the thighs to intersect into the model thinking I could hide the shape inside the model, but remeshing deletes any faces inside of the model. I found a way around this, but now the armatures return the "bone heat weighting" error when I try to use automatic weighting. Envelope weighting doesn't generate desirable results, either. I reckon this is due to me messing with topology to get around my previous issue.

What sounds like my source of error here? Is it Blender not accepting the weighting because of my amateur modeling? Do I need to model the base of the character with the legs parted and apply collision to them later? Is there a simpler solution I'm just unaware of? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! (1) Your problem is not clear and I don't understand what you mean by *"I don't want the inner face of the thighs to appear flat when the thighs aren't touching and do want them to appear flat when they are touching."* - Which inner faces? And what means "flat"? Can you add a screenshot? -- (2) Quote: ... *"...remeshing deletes any faces inside of the model."* <- This doesn't sound good. For animation, you want to have a clean mesh topology that deforms well. Remeshing will mess up everything => bad deformation & [Heat Weighting error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598)

Comment: (3) in Blender, collision detection is only available for physic simulations such as Cloth and Soft Body simulations. Usually, this is used for cloth and not for self-collision of the legs. The armature deforms the mesh. If you need additional corrections you can use *Shape Keys*. But beware this results in extra work and some drawbacks (you cannot apply modifiers to a mesh with shape keys)