# Rigify: Generated Rig doesn't move character

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

I'm following this tutorial https://youtu.be/ILDdIbAwxJM?si=E_iL6qExxnqpAcAC  but the generated rig doesn't the character mesh I'm using

Weirdly enough, then I followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/7VLqDctzvAk?si=vDPvrABl20Ias0sz and then the mesh moves with the armature

Why is my character mesh only able to move by parenting to the armature instead of to the rig?

Edit: the blend file
[image]

Comment: The second tutorial doesn't use Rigify at all so the two tutorials use different methods.

Comment: The armature is the rig. A rig is a generic term for "any system to control the movement and deform objects for animation".  An armature (or skeleton in other softwares) is one of the possible systems you can use as a rig. Both tutorials use the exact same method to parent the mesh to the armature. So if it doesn't work on your side, it only means you messed a step somewhere. Look up for errors in the footer when parenting, they might tell you something is wrong in your mesh or rig and makes the parenting fail. Otherwise, please share your file as @JohnEason mentioned.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hint: if I open up the Console window, then when I try to parent the mesh to the Armature using *Automatice Weights* I see the message ```Warning: Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones```.   However if I parent using envelope weights: success.  I'm not sure why automatic weights don't work in this case.  Perhaps edit your question to include this information for a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones) for solutions.   I simply took the error message and searched in this forum for results.

For example, your "pants" are not connected by edges/faces to the upper part of the body -- is the problem.   There are 5 distinct meshes that are not connected by common edges.
[image]

It must be a single closed form (connect disconnected segments, tedious!), or else separate into two objects and parent each separately to the Armature.
[image]

There was an additional problem with the pants mesh, appears there were some loose vertices,  so the solution here is:

1. Edit mode
2. Select all vertices
3. Mesh :: Merge by Distance

I used something like 0.002m for the distance factor in the popup dialog (not shown):
[image]

The result:  [image]

Comment: when I move the shoulder and arms, the arm sometimes detaches. is there any way to fix that?