# Cannot bind rig to character without error alerts

Tags: auto-rig-pro

I'm having a lot of trouble with the armature for this model. I've been using Auto-Rig pro but I think it is the model itself that is causing problems. The first error I see is:

"Warning, armature scale will be set to 1 (Init Scale is enabled),Compensate scale in current actions to preserve animation?"

This is soon followed by:

"Binding may have partially or totally failed, because of low scale
Bind again with Scale Fix enabled?"

I'm not sure why I get these errors. I have reset the scale on every part of the character. I have even tried increasing the size of the character by 10, but the errors remain.

I can overcome these and get binding eventually, but each time it ignores the Jacket as part of the character and the hands and sleeves move right through it.

Joining all the parts together as one doesn't seem to make any difference either.

[image]

Comment: Problems with Auto-Rig Pro are outside the remit of this Q&A site, but it might help if you could share your Blend file here. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: I assumed it was okay because there is an auto-rig-pro tag that specifically states: " Use this tag for questions about using Auto Rig Pro in Blender."

Comment: To be honest I didn't even know that tag existed. Most of the questions that used it seem to have other tags too.  If you can share your file as I suggested we would be able to look at your model and may be able to see what the problem is likely to be even if we don't have that addon ourselves.

Comment: I've never used Auto-Rig Pro. But have you applied the scale to the model and the armature? (*Ctrl+A > Scale* in *Object* mode). Also make sure the normals point into the right direction (keyword: flipped normals). IDK how the weights are calculated but it seems that it didn't work for the sleeves. This often happens if the mesh as multiple mesh parts. You can fix this problem as you would any other rig -> transfer the weights (https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/223782/107598)