# Baby Mesh Won't Move With Rigify Rig

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

I purchased a rigged baby model from TurboSquid that was rigged in Blender 2.9 which didn't seem to work in 4.0.2.  So, I stripped out the old rig and created a Rigify rig for the model.  Unfortunately, the new rig doesn't control the model.  I've looked at other posts for a solution and tried some suggestions, like face orientation and merging by distance.  I've spent a week rigging and rerigging and I'm at my wit's end here.  I've been using Blender for a few months now so I'm relatively new, but I have a decent amount of experience for a newb, including following some YouTube rigging tutorials successfully. See the photo of my failed rig.  Nothing moves on the mesh, whether I'm in IK or FK mode.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank You!
[image]

[image]

Comment: What size is the baby model? - Rigify doesn't work well (or at all sometimes) with very small objects. If you do scale it up in Object mode, don't forget to apply the scale to both it and the Armature with Ctrl-A > Scale.

Comment: Yes, I did scale it down before rigging it.   The model is at real-world scale, in inches, at 21" tall.   I need to use it in a scene that already has everything to scale.  And yes, I did apply transformations to everything.  Any thoughts?  Thanx!

Comment: You mean you scaled it *up* (not *down*) before parenting the mesh to the armature, right? Scaling *up* the mesh and the armature by factor 10x often does the trick. After the *Parent To* operation, you can revert the scale again to obtain the model in real-world size. Did you use *Parent To > With Automatic Weights*? Is there a yellow error message ([Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598)) in the status bar?

Comment: When I originally got the model I scaled the height down to the real-world size of 21.5" (.546m), the original was 212.24", or 17.69' (5.39m).  (As mentioned above.) Yes, you're correct, when I tried parenting at the smaller scale I got that error message.  So, now I scaled everything back up 10x and applied all transformations.  Then I parented all the meshes, body, diaper, eyes, and mouth parts, to the meta rig with "With Automatic Weights".  There was no error message, great!  However, the mesh still doesn't move in pose mode, and I haven't even scaled it back down yet.  Thank You!

Comment: As I see in the Outliner, the Baby is not child of the rig, while it sholuld if you follow the standard procedure, which is: in Object mode select the baby, shift select the rig, press Ctrl P > with automatic weights. If this doesn't solve, please upload your file.

Comment: I went back and followed the rigging tutorial courses on rigging by CGDrive using my model instead of his, and it looks like I missed a couple of steps, plus I think enlarging the rig and model helped as well.  I'm part of the way through, and I can now move the head, arms, and legs.  I still need to work on the eyes and mouthparts.   I'll finish tomorrow and report back.  Thank You Folks!

Comment: As I mentioned, I've got the head and limbs moving so far, but I'm adjusting the weight painting now and I was able to stop the arm bones from controlling the diaper with weight painting, great.  However, when I try to adjust the weight painting on the body, it appears to be covered with large white vertex points and they somehow prevent me from ALT-Clicking to select any of the deform bones.   See the second image above.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?  Thank You!

Comment: @HorganInnovation Sorry, which second image above?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it looks like this was all caused by operator error.  I now have the Baby fully rigged and functional.  By going back and rigging my model along with the CGDive Rigging course, I was able to see where I messed up and correct it.  Thank You all for taking the time to offer your advice and tips!  It's greatly appreciated! [image]

Comment: To make this a valuable answer to others who might come across the same problem, it would have been good to explain how you messed up and corrected it, to help them avoid the pitfalls. Just saying "do it again and try to make no errors" is as if I would always answer people who have problems with a tutorial: "just watch it again and try to make it right next time".

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon suggested, I'll post a more detailed solution to my rigging issue so others may learn from it. What I messed up on was the parenting steps, in that I didn't do them because I thought the Rigify process took care of it. Even when I went back to see if did a certain operation correctly, I was just looking for that particular part in the video only. So, the parts of the video I forgot about never got viewed because, well, I forgot them. So it wasn't until I rigged my own model (instead of their sample model) along with the video, from start to finish, that I realized what I had missed. So, I would say the biggest lesson here is, if you can, use your own model to follow an instructional video rather than doing it from memory. It would have saved me days of frustration. Thanx Again!