# Not able to control object with rig. "Blender bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones"

Tags: rigging

(EDIT 1! A: Is it possible to add the rig without adjusting the human meta rig at all? I mean, for me it fails just doing that.
B: One post referred to the rig as "Rigify's animation rig". Is that the one I'm using by selecting Add/Armature/Human (Meta-rig) when I have loaded the "Rigging Rigify" in preferences?)

Probably this is a very simple problem to solve, however, I have been working on it for days now. I'm not a regular Blender user - coming from Rhino - so just recalling the basic interface is a challenge on its own. I'm a bit sleep-deprived, so forgive me if I'm rambling.

I want to add the Human (Meta-rig) to use it to create a Rig to control (basically) the hands of my object. But it always delivers this message: "Blender bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones". The rig is just not responding in any mode. Well, I can rotate/move it with the gumball, but that's it.

Steps:

1. Object Mode
   import object
2. Object Mode
   with selected object
   add/armature/human (meta-rig)
3. Edit Mode
   adjust metarig
4. Any? Mode (it's possible to do it in any mode. I dont know which one is correct.
   data/object data properties
   click rig
   (ending up in Oject Mode after creating rig)
5. deselect rig
   select object first
   then select rig
   right click - parent/with automatic weights
   Fail

Log from "System Console":

```
------------------------------------
Read prefs: "C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.0\config\userpref.blend"
Reloading external rigs...
Reloading external metarigs...
Info: Deleted 1 object(s)

Loaded image from: 'G:\Peter Herrhagsg├Ñrden i Falun 231017\3D\A-49-0-B001.jpg'
OBJ import of 'Man med handtransplant 240114-2 boolean-240123-1 meshfelfix RH x 0.002.obj' took 623.9 ms
Fetch rig.
Clear rig animation data.
Create widgets collection: 0.002
Duplicate rig: 0.012
Instantiate rigs: 0.002
Initialize rigs: 0.001
Prepare bones: 0.002
Generate bones: 4.119
Parent bones: 0.025
Configure bones: 0.019
Preapply bones: 0.009
Apply bones: 0.003
Rig bones: 0.033
Generate widgets: 0.029
Assign layers: 0.029
Finalize: 0.032
The rest: 0.028
Info: Successfully generated: "rig"

Warning: Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones
 -----------------------------------------
```

Mistakes adjusted along the way, trying to find the problem: the object is downscaled in Rhino to be able to import in the correct size in Blender to avoid scale issues; faults in mesh fixed before import etc.
I have started over with a fresh document, in v 4.0 and v 3.5. The same result.
Changed object. In the end, I just followed the steps above, not even bothering to adjust the metarig. Then, the Blender rig didn't even like the untouched metarig.

First I was under the impression that the object had to be parented to the metarig (or vice versa, selecting metarig last). But after reading about it in the forum, that didn't seem to be the case, so I skipped that. I've read so many posts and watched so many YouTube clips about the subject, but failed to get it right. I'm really at a loss now. You find a screenshot of the final stage with the object properties of the rig.

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas? Clearing preferences maybe? How?

Comment: Thanks! I'll dive into it. There seem to be many threads to pull there.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15964/heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones?rq=1 probably has better info in it-- less specific to any particular model, more attention from users/Google.  There are a billion of these threads.

Comment: Hi. The mesh is causing the problem, not the metarig. There may be faces that intersect, overlap, or are too close together. This makes the automatic calculation of the weights fail. Then the rig will work only partly or not at all. Check the lips, eyelids, between the fingers, toes, armpits, and the crotch/butt area. Or use the add-on *3D-Print Toolbox* that comes with Blender. One thing you can try is to scale up the mesh and the metarig by a factor of 10. Then try to parent the mesh to the generated rig. If this works, you can scale down the rig again & apply the scale (Object mode, Ctrl+A)

Comment: About your bonus questions: A) the *metarig* is like a template that you have to adapt to your model. It is only used to define the layout of the bones so that Rigify can generate the actual rig that fits your model. B) The generated rig with the default name *rig* is used for the animation, hence the "animation rig". Users who are new to Rigify sometimes try to bind and use the *metarig* for the animation. However, it is not intended to be used in this way.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback.

Comment: Blunder, you're right. The head had like a bubble gum inverted in the mouth, among other faults with the mesh. After clearing that up it's working as it is supposed to. I thought I would go mad. The solution was surely just around the corner, for days. :-))) Thanks!